# How to veritcal-align top and vertical-align middle in same TD

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have an X and a checkmark on top of a box, and in the middle display the title, here is my html

[image]

And here is what the result is:

[image]

However I would like the h5 tag saying workout to be in the middle of the box. Can anyone help me?

Comment: don't add code as images, use snippets please...

Comment: ^ ditto - and vertical align will align elements vertically in relation to the other elements in that line. I think you can use the same html structure and center the h5 with absolute positioning. I'll type it up quick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to accomplish this using flex for positioning.

The td (div in this snippet) has relative positioning so you can use absolute positioning of the top actions with `justify-content:space-between` the items pushing them to the edges.

Then the div containing the h5 you want centered can be set to center vertically with `align-items:center` and horizontally with `justify-content:space-around` as long as you are using `display:flex`.

```html
<div class="table-task" style="width:100px; height: 300px; background: chartreuse; position:relative">
  <div class="top-actions" style="position:absolute; top:0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; display:flex; padding:10px; justify-content:space-between;">
    <span>X</span>
    <span>X</span>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing:border-box; display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content:space-around;">
    <h5>Workout</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```